# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve. Svelte webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack, svelte

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/svelte/index.mjs 1:0-167
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './internal' in '(путь до проекта)/js/reviews-list-widget-svelte/node_modules/svelte'
Did you mean 'index.mjs'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './internal' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is a '*.mjs' file or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
 @ ./reviews.svelte 19:0-37
 @ ./script.js 1:21-59 1:913-920

webpack 5.1.1 compiled with 1 error in 2212 ms
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: './script.js',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      svelte: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'svelte')
    },
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.svelte'],
    mainFields: ['svelte', 'browser', 'module', 'main']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
    filename: 'main.js',
    publicPath: 'js/',
  },
  devServer: {
    overlay: true,
    hot: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svelte$/,
        loader: 'svelte-loader',
        options: {
          hotReload: true,
          // dev: true
        },
      }
    ],
  }
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reviews-list-widget",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "scss-loader": "^0.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.29.0",
    "svelte-loader": "^2.13.6",
    "webpack": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "4.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

reviews.svelte:

```
<script>
import { afterUpdate } from 'svelte';
</script>
```

script.js:

```
import reviews from './reviews.svelte';
  let widgetDiv = document.getElementById('widget');
  const app = new reviews({
    target: widgetDiv
  });
```

Пакеты переустанавливал, кеш чистил.
Путь до node_modules правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Поменял в node_modules/svelte/index.mjs

```
export { SvelteComponentDev as SvelteComponent, afterUpdate, beforeUpdate, createEventDispatcher, getContext, onDestroy, onMount, setContext, tick } from './internal';
```

на:

```
export { SvelteComponentDev as SvelteComponent, afterUpdate, beforeUpdate, createEventDispatcher, getContext, onDestroy, onMount, setContext, tick } from './internal/index.mjs';
```

и собралось

Answer (score 0):

*Измените конфигурацию Webpack на что то подобное

```
   module.exports = {
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json','.vue'],
    
      },
```